# Test Agents not executing in parallel. VSTS

Tags: c#, selenium, azure-devops, nunit

Using VSTS, locally hosted agent pool, selenium tests.

Currently, I possess a local host of machine strictly for use for QA automation. The goal is to have these tests run against the Agent Pool (currently 7 machines) whenever a build occurs.

[image]

I'm running into a small problem where the tests themselves aren't executing in parallel, instead just executing on one machine, though the task is all queued up as a group.

I have set the Agent Phase for the machines to use the Local Automation agent pool, with a designation of using seven machines for the tasks below.

[image]

The Selenium Automation Phase is also set to spread test cases across VMs based on a number of tests and available agents, as shown below.

[image]

Any ideas on why these aren't running simultaneously?

[image]

Comment: Have you purchased multiple self-hosted agents?  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/pipelines/licensing/concurrent-jobs-vsts?view=vsts

Comment: Yes, we have up to 8 currently. We also had this working on multiple agents back in July when we only had one job.

Comment: Based on the screenshot, just a job is running. Can you provide the screenshot of parallel jobs page? (https://{account}.visualstudio.com/_settings/buildqueue?_a=concurrentJobs)